# Repetition of group patterns in a regex pattern

Tags: regex, curl

So, folks, I have this self crafted pattern that works.  After some hours (I am no regex guru) this puppy evolved to parse curl PUT output for me:

```
   ^\s*([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)
    \s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)
```

*(CR in text only for formatting)*

It gives me 'groups' that I access--it works!  Yet the coder in me sees the repetition of a pattern, and it bugs the frack out of me.  I've seen perl *how-small-is-your-pattern* contests over the years that makes me think this could be *much* smaller.  But my attempts to slap a * in it have failed miserably.

So, **The Question Is**: how do write this pattern in a more concise way so that I can still pull out my target groups?

It probably doesn't matter, but here are the groups I am after:

```
$1: percent finished
$2: size uploaded so far
$6: size to upload
$8: average upload rate
```

Update: Further background can by found on a blog post of mine ([How to configure OnMyCommand to generate a progress bar for curl](http://lanai.dietpizza.ch/geekomatic/2009/03/06/1236358080000.html)) that will explain what I am doing and why I am after only a regex pattern.  I'm not actually coding in a language, *per se*...but configuring a tool to use a regex.

Comment: Thanks, nzpcmad...I am a terrible spellar.  (Ha ha)

Comment: Does it matter?  I'm using OnMyCommand for OSX, which I believe uses command line grep, but I could have that wronge.

Comment: Nope.  OnMyCommand only allows a regex.  There is detailed background on a blog post of mine...will add link to Q

Comment: It matters because if it were Perl you could build the regex with code, I will go look at what OnMyCommand does.

Comment: Could you post what you have right now so we have a jumping off place?

Comment: @Chas. Ownens: Fair enough.  When I think perl, I think regex, although I know they two are different...silly me...

Comment: The blog post you linked gives a lot of detail... I know we all like sticking to DRY, but it'd help to at least know which paragraph deals with why you can't use a regex split on \s+ instead. ;)

Comment: @ojrac in the screenshot of the tool he is using I don't see a split option, so I assume that is the reason

Comment: @Stu Thompson The two are pretty synonymous, to the point that the major non-Perl regex library is named PCRE (Perl Compatible Regex Expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is the best I can do:

```
^\s*([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+(?:[^ ]+\s+){3}([^ ]+)\s+[^ ]+\s+([^ ]+)\s+
```

I collapsed the matches you do not care about, made them not capture, and left off the unneeded trailing matches.  If it is important to match everything (e.g. there are other lines that would match this) you can say:

```
^\s*([^ ]+)\s+([^ ]+)\s+(?:[^ ]+\s+){3}([^ ]+)\s+[^ ]+\s+([^ ]+)(?:\s+[^ ]){4}
```

Note, my changes also change the capture numbers:

- $1: percent finished
- $2: size uploaded so far
- $3: size to upload
- $4: average upload rate

You may be able to get away with this if it supports \S

```
^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(?:\S+\s+){3}(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+
```

but it does not mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments elsewhere.  It's bedtime for Bonzo but will test out your options, and others, in the morning.  Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  The first worked (with giggling the capture numbers from my original) for an expression that is only 55% of the original.  I didn't try the second as it was longer.  The third did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
((^\s*|\s+)([^ ]+)){12}
```

If you do not care about the number of matches and want to match a complete string, just stick with the following.

```
((^\s*|\s+)([^ ]+))*\s*$
```

Comment: At least in Perl that doesn't work, you only get the last of the 11 repeated matches in the capture.

Comment: I am using .NET/C#. So I cannot tell about ather regex implementations.

Comment: Doesn't look like it works in JavaScript either. I don't know what regex implementation he's working with, but I doubt it'll capture the groups he needs with a {12}.

Comment: .NET lets you break out individual captures from repeated groups, but AFAIK it's unique in that regard. Also, the only way to retrieve individual captures is via API calls like M.Groups(2).Captures(6). (Maybe someday there will be a shorthand notation like "$2#6", but I doubt it.) This is not a solution Stu can use.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex uses greedy matching this might work:

```
^(\s*([^ ]+))+$
```

explanation:

- ^ = start of line
- repeated pattern = \s*([^ ]+)
- surround that with parens and add '+' to indicate 'one or more matches of the preceeding'
- $ = end of line

Comment: it looks like he is trying to extract four distinct values from the output, this produces two captures, one of which is a submatch of the other.